# Combining -webkit-mask and -webkit-transform on Android default browser

Tags: android, css, css-transforms

On an Android 4.3 device, using the default browser, I'm creating an element that uses both `-webkit-mask` and `-webkit-transform: rotate`. But when I combine the two styles, the element's background color doesn't get masked correctly.

Here's what it looks like without the rotation (top) and with it (bottom). As you can see, the bottom image doesn't have the background masked:

[image: android]

And here's what I'm expecting. This is what I get on Chrome and other browsers:

[image: chrome]

The bottom element has the following styles (the full source is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7qjgtaet/)):

```
background-color: red;
-webkit-mask: center center url('data:image/png;base64,...') no-repeat;
-webkit-mask-size: 2em 3em;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
```

Is this a known issue with the stock Android browser? Any way around it?

Answer (score -3):

I'm not an expert, but have you tried:

```
body {
background-color: transparent;
```

}

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.